# Sharing a video in iOS on YouTube, Facebook etc

Tags: ios, facebook, video, youtube

Question is for iOS 8 & Xcode 6. I have an app where a user makes a video (*.mov or *.avi) with in the app and then I need to have the ability to share that video on either YouTube, facebook etc.

I am able to save the video in users camera roll and when I select the share option in Apple native Photos app on a real device I see this screenshot. I see Youtube, Facebook, Vimo etc.

[image]

Now in my app I use UIDocumentIntractionController. When I use that to share my video I don't see YouTube, Facebook options coming up. NOTE: These two apps are installed on my device yet they don't appear on the sheet

[image]

My question is it possible for us developers to have access to the same action sheet that Apple Shows when sharing Videos? If so just point me in that direction and I will read up. I have been googling and searching for a while and the only question I came close to is this here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961480/share-a-video-with-ios

which has no answers. I can only assume its not possible and I will have to download and implement each 3rd party SDK individually?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?